# Get values from keys matching pattern in rocks db

Tags: rust, rocksdb

Is it possible to read all values matching key pattern from rocks db.
e.g:

```
key1 -> value1
key12 -> value12
key123 -> value123
```

I want to ready all keys matching pattern => "key1*" or "key*2"

Is there a way to perform this kind of search operation in Rocks Db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `key1*` yes: You can use `rocksdb::DB::iterator` with `RocksDB::IteratorMode::From("key1".as_bytes(), rocksdb::Direction::Forward)`, and then put a `.take_while(|(k, _)| k.starts_with("key1".as_bytes()))` to stop it from leaving `key1*`.
- `key*2` no

Why is this tagged Rust?

Comment: i am using rocks db with rust, thats why i thought to use rust tag. thanks for the suggestion , i will try this

Comment: Might want to mention that. ;)